# Defining a TypeScript debug variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm running into a brick wall with what I guess should be a simple task - I want a single variable that determines if the application is in debug state - i.e. `debug = false` so that I can use this variable, as you may expect, in any class and log messages accordingly. Annoyingly however, no matter what I try, I simply cannot get access to this variable.

I have an `app.ts` file that imports every class and instantiates them. Defining a global variable at the top of this file did not work, and likewise defining them in a `global.d.ts` file did not work either - the compiler simply cannot see them. For the record my `tsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "files": [
    "./resources/assets/js/declarations/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

The `global.d.ts` file itself is incredibly simple...

```
declare let appDebug: boolean;
```

And its value is set in the `app.ts` file as mentioned previously. What gives? How can I essentially pass this value into every class?

Answer (score 0):

The `files` setting doesn't support globs/patterns - only an explicit list of files, so you should see an error when you try to compile in typescript via `tsc -p .` complaining about the `"./resources/assets/js/declarations/**/*.d.ts"` bit.

Documentation here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html